# Ubuntu server 16.04. Некорректная работа NetworkManager.

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть

Ubuntu server 16.04 без ubuntu-desktop. Ставлю NetworkManager. Включаю его. Перезагружаю. Работает пока нормально. Задаю карточке адрес статический. Перезагружаю  ОС. Появляется для соединения на одну карточку(со старым и новым адресами). Удаляю со старым адресом и перезагружаю ОС. После загрузки снова два профиля. Логи говорят, что при загрузке создаётся новый профиль. Это нормально для NetworkManager. Мучаюсь с проблемой более суток.

Comment: да, насколько я знаю, это вполне нормально для networkmanager. его установка и использование, с моей точки зрения, могут быть оправданы разве что лишь в случае неопытных пользователей устройства, и лишь в тех устройствах, что постоянно переключаются между разными сетями.

Comment: А Вы знаете причину создания дублируещего интерфейса?

Comment: А зачем вообще создавать статический адрес?Если сделать его динамическим, то проблем вообще не должно быть.

Comment: Я хочу докапаться в чём проблема NetworkManager. А с такими проблемами я его вообще не хочу использовать в Ubuntu server 16

Comment: Неужели мало людей которые могут посоветовать, что делать с NetworkManager. Использовать его или нет